# UvaOnlineJudge Wrong Answer Train Tracks 11586

Tags: java, logic

I think I have tried every possible test case. But still get wrong answer. Please Help. Problem Link :
https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=2633

```
class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Scanner cin = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(args[0]));


    int n = Integer.parseInt(cin.nextLine());



    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        String s ;

            s = cin.nextLine();     
            s = s.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");




        boolean isItTrue = true;
        int m1=0;
        int mfs[] = new int[4];//mm==0,ff==1,mf=2,fm=3


        for (int j = 0; j < s.length() -1 ; j += 3) {

            switch (s.subSequence(j, j + 2)+""){

                case "MM" :  
                mfs[0]++;break;
                case "FF" :  
                mfs[1]++;break;
                case "MF" :  
                mfs[2]++;break;
                case "FM" :  
                mfs[3]++;break;


            }
            m1++;

        }

        if(m1<2)
        {

            isItTrue = false;
        }


        if((mfs[0]!=mfs[1] ))
            isItTrue = false;

        if(isItTrue)
            System.out.println("Loop");
        else
            System.out.println("No Loop");


    }

   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you want to create 2 arrays of strings. The first array represents the track that you've laid down and the second array represents the available pieces.

First you fill the second array with all of the strings for the pieces (MM, MF, FM, FF). Then, you take the first piece and add it to your track array. You get the last letter of that piece and then search the available pieces for a corresponding first letter match. You continue to do this, checking the last letter of the last item in the track against all available pieces until all of the pieces have been used or there is no match. If there isn't a match, you'd return false. If all of the pieces have been used, then you want to check to make sure the first letter of your first string matches with the last letter of your last string. If that is true, then you return true.

Here's the code to do that.

```
class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
//Scanner cin = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(args[0]));


int n = Integer.parseInt(cin.nextLine());



for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    String s ;
    String[] available = s.split(" ");
    String[] track = new String[available.length];
    track[0] = available[0];
    available[0] = null;

    boolean isItTrue = true;
    for(int i = 1; i<available.length;i++){
       String last = track[i-1].substring(1);
       for(int q = 0; q<available.length;q++)
       {
          if(available[q] != null)
          {
             String first = available[q].substring(0,1);
             if(!(first.equals(last)){
                 track[i] = available[q];
                 available[q] = null;
                 break;
             }
           //This means there is no matching available track.
            if(q == (available.length -1))
                isItTrue = false;
          }

       }
    }
    //Checks the very beginning against the very end
    if(!(track[0].substring(0,1).equals(track[track.length-1].substring(1)))
    {
      isItTrue = false;
    }
    if(isItTrue)
        System.out.println("Loop");
    else
        System.out.println("No Loop");


}

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was printing Loop and No Loop instead LOOP and NO LOOP